# How to append list from JSON array?

Tags: html, arrays, json, append

I want for loop or for each or both codes for learning both ways to make the format like,I want the to acccess the id "list" to append li.

HTML

```
<div id="list">
            <ul>
                <li>Mainland China</li>
                <li>Hotel Park Inn</li>
                ....
            </ul>
</div>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input data-inline="true" id="submit"  type="submit" value="Go">
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {

        var data='{"restaurant": {"results": [{"name": "The Astor"},{"name": "Mainland China"},{"name": "Bhojohori Manna"},{"name": "6 Ballygunge Place"},{"name": "Zaranj"},{"name": "Hotel Park Inn"},{"name": "Oh! Calcutta"},{"name": "Red Hot Chilli Pepper"},{"name": "Chinoiserie"}]}}';

var json = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(json.restaurant.results.length);

        alert(json.restaurant.results[0].name);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add below line inside click function.

```
        var list = $('#list');
        jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        jsonData.restaurant.results.forEach(function(i){
            list.append('<li>'+i.name+'</li>');            
        });
```

EDIT:-

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        jsonData.restaurant.results.forEach(function(i){
            $('ul').append('<li>'+i.name+'</li>');            
        });
```

Comment: and what initially tags should be there in the html or fully blank or partially blank such as div with id ,ul,li,etc?<div id="list">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
</div>